# Attach an captured image to an email on clicking a button

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have captured image from iphone using the below `UIImagePickerController` delegate method.

```
    - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    self.myImageView.image = image;  
    //    [self performSelector:@selector(emailButtonPressed:) withObject:image afterDelay:1.0];
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}
```

See above `emailButtonPressed` method it was called by `self`. I want to call this in a button action. 
I wrote the code below for `emailButtonPressed`.

```
- (void)emailButtonPressed:(UIImage *)image
{  
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailview=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];      mailview.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:55/255.0 green:190/255.0 blue:55/255.0 alpha:1];  
        mailview.mailComposeDelegate=self;  
        // NSMutableString *subject=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Testing"];  
        [mailview setSubject:@"Picture from my iPhone!"];  
        //   NSString *email_new=@"";  
        [mailview setMessageBody:@"Description" isHTML:NO];  

        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);  

        [mailview addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ImageName"];  
        [self presentModalViewController:mailview animated:YES];  
}
```

sorry for any mistakes in my code.

Comment: What's your question? Please provide more info.

Comment: So what is the question here? How to create a UIButton and set action?

Comment: When i capture the image delegate method automatically called and attached that image to email clear up to this.Now my question is how can i attach that image on a button click @llija Tovilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `emailButtonPressed` method as follows,

```
- (void)emailButtonPressed //removed the param
{  
        UIImage *image = self.myimageview.image; //or set some other param as image = self.image; whichever you set in picker delegate method
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailview=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];      mailview.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:55/255.0 green:190/255.0 blue:55/255.0 alpha:1];  
        mailview.mailComposeDelegate=self;  
        // NSMutableString *subject=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Testing"];  
        [mailview setSubject:@"Picture from my iPhone!"];  
        //   NSString *email_new=@"";  
        [mailview setMessageBody:@"Description" isHTML:NO];  

        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);  

        [mailview addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"ImageName"];  
        [self presentModalViewController:mailview animated:YES];  
}
```

Keep this method as is,

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    self.myImageView.image = image;  //instead of this, you can create an @property for image in .h file and assign to that also here.
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}
```

Assuming that you have declared your email button as,

```
UIButton *emailbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; //or any other way
```

Now add this method as your button target immediately after that line,

```
[emailbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(emailButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now on tap of `emailbutton` whatever image you have set in `self.myimageview.image` in `UIImagePickerController` delegate will be sent as an attachment.

Comment: so there is no need to give the UIImagePicker delegate method ok clear ed my doubt@ACB